# Spring Boot 2 @OrderBy being ignored

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have two entities:

```
public class Field {
    private String inputType;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "field")
    @OrderBy("order_by")
    private List<SelectItem> selectItems;
}

public class SelectItem {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "field_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Field field;

    private int orderBy;
}
```

It seems that Hibernate is ignoring the `@OrderBy` annotation in the Field class when selecting the SelectItems associated with a Field instance. I know this because 1) the ordering is not according to the `orderBy` value and 2) when I intentionally misspell the value in the `@OrderBy` annotation, everything still works.

In fact, I don't even see evidence in the log that Hibernate is even selecting from the `select_items` table. Something must be because when I look at the values being returned from the repository, the `SelectItems` are in there, but the query isn't printing in the log, as all the rest of the queries do.

This is from my log:

```
Hibernate: insert into fields (created_by, modified_by, modified_date, category, disabled, hidden, input_type, is_integer, label, max, min, name, is_number, order_by, positive_number, required, suffix, uuid, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into select_items (descr, field_id, order_by, selected, uuid, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into select_items (descr, field_id, order_by, selected, uuid, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into select_items (descr, field_id, order_by, selected, uuid, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into select_items (descr, field_id, order_by, selected, uuid, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into select_items (descr, field_id, order_by, selected, uuid, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: select field0_.id as id1_18_, field0_.created_by as created_2_18_, field0_.created_date as created_3_18_, field0_.modified_by as modified4_18_, field0_.modified_date as modified5_18_, field0_.category as category6_18_, field0_.disabled as disabled7_18_, field0_.hidden as hidden8_18_, field0_.input_type as input_ty9_18_, field0_.is_integer as is_inte10_18_, field0_.label as label11_18_, field0_.max as max12_18_, field0_.min as min13_18_, field0_.name as name14_18_, field0_.is_number as is_numb15_18_, field0_.order_by as order_b16_18_, field0_.positive_number as positiv17_18_, field0_.required as require18_18_, field0_.suffix as suffix19_18_, field0_.uuid as uuid20_18_ from fields field0_ where field0_.category=? and field0_.name=?
```

There is no subsequent select statement in the log that would pull the nested `SelectItem` instances--yet they are there when I get the object back.

So somehow they are being selected, but it doesn't appear that hibernate is doing it, and whatever is selecting them is ignoring the `@OrderBy` annotation.

Can someone please explain what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It is missing to specific `order type ASC or DESC` and call it directly by field name.

```
@OrderBy("orderBy ASC")
```

Comment: That doesn't work. The entire annotation is being ignored. I just tried your suggestion (no difference) and then tried  @OrderBy("orderxxxxBy ASC"), which isn't even a property of the object. No change, no error; the object is returned along with all of the children, but they aren't ordered properly.

Comment: Ok then you might use `@OrderColumn(name = "order_by")` @ukalumni

Comment: Tried that, and at least gave an interesting exception: Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Table [select_items] contains physical column name [order_by] referred to by multiple physical column names: [order_by], [orderBy]

I got around that by adding @Column(name="order_by") above the orderBy property in SelectItem.java, but the end result was the same: the code works but the SelectItems are not sorted by orderBy and the select statement never shows up in the log.